# Recurrence relation for the number of regions created by 'n' mutually intersecting circles on a piece of paper

Tags: combinatorics

Find a recurrence relation for the number of regions created by 'n' mutually intersecting circles on a piece of paper (no three circles have a common intersecting point).

> I know that $R_1 = 2$, $R_2 = 4$, $R_3 = 8$, and $R_4 = 14$, so I deduce that $R_n = R_{n-1} + R_{n-2} +2$
>   But I have to find a closed formula for Rn and I don't know how.

Comment: [OEIS A014206](https://oeis.org/A014206)

Answer (score 0):

Have another think about what the recurrence relation is ...

If you have $n$ circles, there will be $2n$ intersections when you introduce a new circle, this will introduce $2n$ new regions.